# Encrypt a filename in C# without including unusable chars in the resulting string

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I want to encrypt a filename but ensure that the encrypted filename doesn't contain any of the characters that are not allowed (on a windows system) in filenames.

The string also needs to be able to be decrypted back to the original filename (so you can't just filter out the invalid characters after the encryption).

To my knowledge the unusable characters are \ / : * ? " > < |.  I'm aware of System.IO.Path.InvalidPathChars but I don't know of an encryption method that will avoid those characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert the filename, or the encrypted output, to MIME Base64 encoding. I don't believe that standard uses any of the prohibited characters. (Even if it does, you can `.Replace()` prohibited characters with nonprohibited ones.)

For example, your question base64'd is:
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=

Comment: +1 - as noted here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64, "MIME Base64 uses A–Z, a–z, and 0–9 for the first 62 values."

Comment: The problem lies in those last two values.  They're `+` and `/`.

Comment: Of course, it's a simple character replacement to swap `/` with, say, `-`. And then swap it back before the decode.

Comment: A simple two-way String.Replace to any of the many other acceptable characters (just not A-Za-z0-9) would fix that.

Answer (score 4):

As @Tom notes, you can base64 encode the file name.  However, .NET's base64 methods include the slash character, so you'll need to replace that.

```
var encryptedFilename = GetEncryptedFileName();
var encodedFileName = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptedFilename));
var encodedAndEscapedFilename = encodedFileName.Replace('/', '-');
```

You can then do basically the same thing in reverse to get the original name (using `Convert.FromBase64String` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetString`).

Comment: thanks, I just encountered that problem, I appreciate the comment!

Answer (score 3):

There is no resulting 'string', all encryption transformations result in byte[] not in string. There are string representations of byte[], like the well knows hex (0xBAADF00D) or Base64. Probably base64 is the most appropiate, just use [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) and [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx).

That being said encrypting a file name seems like a very bad idea. File names are by definition index lookup keys and with encryption you will loose any lookup ability. You will have to scan the entire disk/folder and decrypt each file name just to find out the file you want. Note that you cannot rely on a known encrypted value (eg. if I seek 'file.txt' I encrypt 'file.txt' and then search for the encrypted name) because encryption has to use a random [IV](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.ivvalue.aspx) value (which is appended to the encryption result). Failure to properly randomize the IV will result in [cribs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crib_(cryptanalysis)). Yet succesful salting the key (good random IV) will make the result unsearchable.

Comment: Thanks I guess.  Once I encrypt the filename I can probably manage to not put the file in some random place and lose it.

Comment: And an attacker will be stopped from looking up the encrypted file name there by... what exactly? You can do as you wish, i don't really care, I just want to shed some light for the innocent readers stumbling on this from google two months later.

Comment: This is nothing but an (unclever) way to replace Path.GetRandomFileName

Comment: It's cool, relax.  The file name has important info in it and the file isn't moving so it shouldn't get lost.  I agree that encrypting file names all over the file system wouldn't be a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

As Remus stated above there is no resulting 'string', all encryption transformations result in byte[] not in string.

I generally take an encryption output byte array, and call `BitConverter.ToString(Bytes);` to convert it to hex, though this does result in a FF-D0-FF-D1 format. If a plain hex string is required, just run a `.Replace("-", "");`

e.g.

> return
>   BitConverter.ToString(AESEncryption.Encrypt(token,
>   `key)).Replace("-", "");`

(AESEncryption is a simple custom built wrapper around RijndaelManaged)

Decryption isn't quite as neat, a bit brute force, but still simple

```
    private byte[] FromHexString(string encryptedToken)
    {
        List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= encryptedToken.Length; i+=2)
        {
            try
            {
                bytes.Add((byte)Int32.Parse(encryptedToken.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
            }
            catch //whatever exception
            {
                //handle
            }

        }

        return bytes.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer was to convert the encrypted code to HEX. The benefit to this was compatibility between ASP, ASPX, SQL, VB, C#, and Javascript.
Another benefit was that I could use the encryption of my choice without worrying about the output.